# Where is the Spyder Terminal (yeah, I downloaded it)?

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I **downloaded** the **Spider Terminal plugin** from Github via Anaconda Prompt though, **I can't find the Terminal** when I **boot Spyder** -_- .

Does someone know Where it is ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it appeared as a tab next to the IPyhton consoles.

You can click View -> Panes -> Terminal to toggle it on and off, that should help you find where it is.

Comment: it's none in version 4.0.1, needs the terminal power to use some utility.

Comment: You hit it,it's none in version 4.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

For Spyder `4.0.1`, you need to install the terminal explicitly using

> conda install spyder-terminal -c spyder-ide

Restart spyder and after installation, you'd see `View> Panes > Terminal`. The `Terminal` can be seen adjacent to the `IPython console` and `History` tab at the bottom.

Checkout [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal) is repo for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Anaconda Prompt, you can change working directory to the project you are working on. Then you can write all the commands in anaconda prompt. No need for terminal.

Unfortunately, unlike PyCharm, Spyder does not have default terminal.