# Unable to run feature files using behave on Spyder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, spyder, python-behave

When I try step three of below tutorial:
https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

"Run behave"

Using terminal on vscode: I just type "`behave`" and my feature files run properly.
However, when I use iPython console on Spyder, getting below error-

```
  File "<ipython-input-20-35bd367acbcb>", line 1, in <module>
    behave

NameError: name 'behave' is not defined
```

Is it something to do with the python interpreter being used?
Also features file are run easily on Pycharm. Then why not Spyder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

behave is not a python command, it's a terminal (bash) command.
IPython is a python terminal- meaning it will run python code not bash commands

Comment: To expand on Tamir's answer: you can't run the `behave` command in Spyder's IPython console. You need to use a system terminal (xterm, cmd.exe or Terminal.app) to do that.

Comment: Alright thanks this explains it.
So was wondering if there's a way to use terminal window on Spyder instead of iPython console?

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909923/where-is-the-spyder-terminal-yeah-i-downloaded-it